# Using default value to procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, cursor

For this procedure, if i pass 1 and 2 separately, it should give me two different results.
But if I do not pass any parameter, proc should return data of both parameters 1 and 2.

The problem is getting data for default NULL value. How can i do this ? should i use ref cursors ?
or is there any way I can put a if/case condition in 'where' clause ?
 -- 1 for partitioned, 2 for non-partitioned tables, NULL as default

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE stats(p_run_type IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ) IS
    ...

BEGIN
    FOR c IN
       (  SELECT  exe_order
                 ,table_name
                 ,exec_gather_stat
          FROM   view_stats
          WHERE  exe_order = p_run_type             
         )
  LOOP
   BEGIN
<..do insert..>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `nvl` should do the trick:

```
...
WHERE  exe_order = nvl(p_run_type, exe_order)
...
```

This will take all possible values of `exe_order` if `p_run_type` is null.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `nvl`, you could also do:

```
WHERE (p_run_type IS NULL OR exe_order = p_run_type)
```

This may generate a better (or at least different) plan if `exe_order` is indexed.